# Understanding git tag in different namespaces

Tags: git, namespaces, tags, git-tag

I want to create tags in different namespaces.
Read up on: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces but I am not sure, I understand it correctly.
So, lets say
I create a tag and push it upstream using:
`git -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin refs/tags/20221208_144648`

Now see the tags using:
`git ls-remote --tags <repo_url.git> refs/tags/*`

This works great.

Now, lets say I want to create a tag in a namespace:

```
export GIT_NAMESPACE=foo
git -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
```

or

```
git -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin refs/namespace/foo/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
```

I only see the tag that I first created when I run:

```
git ls-remote --tags <repo_url.git> refs/tags/*
```

Even tried:

```
git ls-remote --tags <repo_url.git> refs/namespace/foo/tags/*
```

I am clearly missing something here. Any explanation will be appreciated.

***Updating my question based on the responses below:***

So here is what I tried:

1. Created a new repo which has no tags

   `$git ls-remote origin refs/tags/* $`
2. Created a tag:

   `git tag 20221208_144648_TEST -m messages`
3. Set the namespace:

   `export GIT_NAMESPACE=foo`
4. Pushed the ref

   `git -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST`
5. List the refs

   ```
   $git ls-remote origin refs/tags/*
   362cb81e90fca03c73e0d3e5ea44883c6298a598    refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
   538a4686d9dd17c1a7d770e718d21b95507393c1    refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST^{}
   ```
6. Unset the namespace

   `unset GIT_NAMESPACE`
7. List remote refs

   ```
   git ls-remote origin refs/tags/*
   362cb81e90fca03c73e0d3e5ea44883c6298a598    refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
   538a4686d9dd17c1a7d770e718d21b95507393c1    refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST^{}
   ```

note: I don't see the namespace yet.

Answer (score 2):

You missed an `s` in `refs/namespaces` (not `refs/namespace`), and the reference path should be `refs/namespaces/foo/refs/tags/xxx` not `refs/namesapces/foo/tags/xxx` (the `refs/` before `tags/` was missed), but neither are the point.

You can use either way (`GIT_NAMESPACE` or `refs/namespaces/`) to specify a namespace, **but not both!**

If you exported `GIT_NAMESPACE=foo` and then pushed an object to `refs/namespaces/foo/refs/tags/`, then it would actually be pushed to `refs/namespaces/foo/refs/namespaces/foo/refs/tags`, equivalent to namespace `foo/foo`.

Actually, I tried with your steps and get expected results.

Steps:

```
git tag 20221208_144648_TEST -m messages

export GIT_NAMESPACE=foo

git -c core.quotepath=false push -v origin refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
```

Results:

```
$ git ls-remote origin refs/tags/*
a750776e2ce551b597a87804424e95b90f26b391        refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
852d0196ca768d181bb027d0f37a0913b00bc7cf        refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST^{}
```

After `unset GIT_NAMESPACE`:

```
$ git ls-remote origin refs/tags/*
a750776e2ce551b597a87804424e95b90f26b391        refs/namespaces/foo/refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST
852d0196ca768d181bb027d0f37a0913b00bc7cf        refs/namespaces/foo/refs/tags/20221208_144648_TEST^{}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me still. Please see my updates in the question above.

Comment: @iDev Which version of git are you using? I’m using 2.38.0.

Comment: I am using: 2.32.0

Answer (score 0):

You used `--tags`, so it only searches `refs/tags/*` for the refs that match the pattern. However, the pattern is `refs/namespace/foo/tags/*`. None of the tags would match the pattern. Use `git ls-remote <repo_url.git> refs/namespace/foo/tags/*` instead.